# Multi row scrolling gallery horizantally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you please help me how to do multi row image scrolling when cursor move up and down but images should be move horizontally.

I need exactly this https://www.johnsonbanks.co.uk/work

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Stack overflow isnt a free coding service.

Comment: Update you question with what you have tried?

Comment: Thanks for responding for my question. I have tried just like this :https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/WmyKWO.  and how can it be increasing thumbnail size from bottom to top. If possible can you explain multiple row. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: [Horizontal Scrolling with mouse wheel](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/WmyKWO)

If you want to move faster, multiply scrollLeft with a number over 50, for a decent speed.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 70);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is only for one row of items, for multiple rows I think that you must use events to connect different containers. I didn't try and I don't know how to do that, but from that example you can have a start. Have fun xD

Comment: Thanks for responding for my question. and how can it be increasing thumbnail size from bottom to top. If possible can you explain multiple row. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is what I did  https://jsfiddle.net/EliasBlack/renxc972/36/  - every row has a different speed but they are not connected between them.. each row has it's own scroll. I don't know how to connect all rows to respond to same scroll, I tried some methods but no succes. Maybe you can use something from here :)